# What is the intuition behind topological sort to find the shortest distance in weighted DAG?

Tags: c++, data-structures, graph, shortest-path, topological-sort

```
#include<iostream>
#include <list>
#include <stack>
#include <limits.h>
#define INF INT_MAX
using namespace std;
 
class AdjListNode
{
        int v;
        int weight;
    public:
        AdjListNode(int _v, int _w)
        {
            v = _v;
            weight = _w;
        }
        int getV()
        {
            return v;
        }
        int getWeight()
        {
            return weight;
        }
};
 
// Class to represent a graph using adjacency list representation
class Graph
{
        int V; // No. of vertices'
 
        // Pointer to an array containing adjacency lists
        list<AdjListNode> *adj;
 
        // A function used by shortestPath
        void topologicalSortUtil(int v, bool visited[], stack<int> &Stack);
    public:
        Graph(int V); // Constructor
 
        // function to add an edge to graph
        void addEdge(int u, int v, int weight);
 
        // Finds shortest paths from given source vertex
        void shortestPath(int s);
};
 
Graph::Graph(int V)
{
    this->V = V;
    adj = new list<AdjListNode> [V];
}
 
void Graph::addEdge(int u, int v, int weight)
{
    AdjListNode node(v, weight);
    adj[u].push_back(node); // Add v to u's list
}
 
void Graph::topologicalSortUtil(int v, bool visited[], stack<int> &Stack)
{
    // Mark the current node as visited
    visited[v] = true;
 
    // Recur for all the vertices adjacent to this vertex
    list<AdjListNode>::iterator i;
    for (i = adj[v].begin(); i != adj[v].end(); ++i)
    {
        AdjListNode node = *i;
        if (!visited[node.getV()])
            topologicalSortUtil(node.getV(), visited, Stack);
    }
 
    // Push current vertex to stack which stores topological sort
    Stack.push(v);
}
 
void Graph::shortestPath(int s)
{
    stack<int> Stack;
    int dist[V];
 
    // Mark all the vertices as not visited
    bool *visited = new bool[V];
    for (int i = 0; i < V; i++)
        visited[i] = false;
 
    // Call the recursive helper function to store Topological Sort
    // starting from all vertices one by one
    for (int i = 0; i < V; i++)
        if (visited[i] == false)
            topologicalSortUtil(i, visited, Stack);
 
    // Initialize distances to all vertices as infinite and distance
    // to source as 0
    for (int i = 0; i < V; i++)
        dist[i] = INF;
    dist[s] = 0;
 
    // Process vertices in topological order
    while (Stack.empty() == false)
    {
        // Get the next vertex from topological order
        int u = Stack.top();
        Stack.pop();
 
        // Update distances of all adjacent vertices
        list<AdjListNode>::iterator i;
        if (dist[u] != INF)
        {
            for (i = adj[u].begin(); i != adj[u].end(); ++i)
                if (dist[i->getV()] > dist[u] + i->getWeight())
                    dist[i->getV()] = dist[u] + i->getWeight();
        }
    }
 
    // Print the calculated shortest distances
    for (int i = 0; i < V; i++)
        (dist[i] == INF) ? cout << "INF " : cout << dist[i] << " ";
}
 
// Driver program to test above functions
int main()
{
    // Create a graph given in the above diagram.  Here vertex numbers are
    // 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 with following mappings:
    // 0=r, 1=s, 2=t, 3=x, 4=y, 5=z
    Graph g(6);
    g.addEdge(0, 1, 5);
    g.addEdge(0, 2, 3);
    g.addEdge(1, 3, 6);
    g.addEdge(1, 2, 2);
    g.addEdge(2, 4, 4);
    g.addEdge(2, 5, 2);
    g.addEdge(2, 3, 7);
    g.addEdge(3, 4, -1);
    g.addEdge(4, 5, -2);
 
    int s = 1;
    cout << "Following are shortest distances from source " << s << " \n";
    g.shortestPath(s);
 
    return 0;
}
```

What is the intuition behind the topological sort to find the shortest path from a source vertex to all other vertices in a weighted directed acyclic graph?

I know the topological sort returns the ordering of vertices in increasing order of their in-degree but unable to figure out how it is helping to find the shortest path.

Comment: There is no intuition there is only graph theory. But the idea is to "drag" the shortest route through the graph, and if you reach a node via a shorter path then you found so far replace the path.

Comment: "topological sort returns the ordering of vertices in increasing order of their in-degree"  This is not true.

Comment: Aside: this code gratuitously uses pointers: `list<AdjListNode> *adj;` could be `list<AdjListNode> adj;` and `bool * visited` could be `std::vector<bool>`. You don't need `new` in application code

Comment: `int dist[V];` -- This is not valid C++ code.  Arrays in C++ must have their size denoted by a compile-time expression, not a runtime value.  This should be `std::vector<int> dist(V);`.  Is this code a version of one found on so-called "competitive coding" or similar websites?  It looks familiar, as these same issues in your code appears in all of those samples found.

Comment: Code is copied from a website, I want to know why we are using topological sort before performing bfs. It will work without using topo sort.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Intuition behind the algorithm to compute single source shortest path for every vertex in DAG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37253739/intuition-behind-the-algorithm-to-compute-single-source-shortest-path-for-every)